# Visual Studio 2012 installation stuck at Microsoft Web Deploy 3.0 step

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to install Visual Studio 2012 ultimate  on my Windows 7 machine, it get stuck at applying Microsoft Web Deploy 3.0 step: i am downloading package sources on process. please help me to overcome this problem. thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Support Site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2896302)

> Visual Studio 2012 may fail to install after October 7, 2013

You need to download the package externally. For more information On their [site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2896302) they are providing Resolution how to solve this issue.

You can download [Web Deploy 3.5](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response.. will the problem be solved if i install web deploy 3.5 for VS 2012? or better to download the latest version of VS?

Comment: I would recommend latest version of VS.